# How do I move nested leading spaces with regex/javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

Can/how do you do a multipart regex replace that looks for content within some tags then moves any space padding outside of the tags?

sample start string:

> random text to ignore** some text **other text to ignore** other
> important text** blah blah blah

result:

> random text to ignore **some text** other text to ignore **other
> important text** blah blah blah

basically trying to help a markdown to html library parse correctly where it is having trouble with spaces right after MD age so i want to do a quick scrub first. The conversion will be done in python with markdown2 or in javascript with showdown.js.

I am hoping for a syntax like s.replace(regex, '$1**$2**$3') where 1 and 3 would be spaces within the tags, if they exist

Comment: So it looks like you want to "move" the `<>` around?

Comment: pretty much... for some reason both parsers dont like markdown bold tags that have spaces right before or after them. Im not giving up on making the editor component export the markdown in a fashion that play nice with the parser that uses the markdown, but would be nice to have this for a bandaid

Comment: Regex could solve this but there would be some edge cases that would completely break it... Anyways I think `s.replace(/([^*]+)\*\* *([^*]+) *\*\*([^*]+)/g, "$1 **$2** $3")` could do it? ` *` is any optional repeating spaces, `[^*]` is anything BUT asterisks.

Comment: any examples you can think of? I have it just about working leveraging s.replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/gm, replaceFn);

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
text.replace(/\*{2}(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)\*{2}/g, '$1**$2**$3')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iJp9Kc/1). *Details*:

- `\*{2}` - a `**` string
- `(\s*)`  - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (use `[^]*?` or `[\w\W]*?` to match across line breaks)
- `(\s*)`  - Group 3 (`$3`): zero or more whitespaces
- `\*{2}` - a `**` string

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "random text to ignore** some text **other text to ignore** other important text** blah blah blah";
console.log(text.replace(/\*{2}(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)\*{2}/g, '$1**$2**$3'));
```